# Failed dependencies

Tags: fedora, software-installation, package-management

I'm on fedora 25 and i'm trying to install a .rpm file but it says  warning:

```
/home/razvan/Downloads/"the file i want to install".rpm:Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 98ab5139: NOKEY error: Failed dependencies:
libQt5X11Estras.so5()(64bit) is needed by .rpm file
libQt5X11Estras.so5(Qt_5)(64bit) is needed by .rpm file
libSDL-1.2.so.0()(64bit) is needed by .rpm file
libpython2.7.so.0()(64bit) is needed by .rpm file
python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by .rpm file
```

What should I do?

Comment: Install the dependencies.

Comment: how are you trying to install the RPM? What commands do you run? Where does the RPM come from?

Comment: i use rpm -i home/razvan/Downloads/name of the file. It comes from virtual box site

Comment: i am following a training and it has a pdf where it explains how to install debian, but in the videos he uses fedora and i had to install it by my own

Comment: Try `dnf install /home/razvan/Downloads/name `, which should pull in the needed dependencies automatically if found.

Comment: and in the tutorial he downloads VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.12_112440_fedora25-1.x86_64.rpm and installs it in fedora, but when i try it, it gave me what i wrote in my question

Comment: Thx Thomas, that solved it

Comment: @Thomas Post answers as answers, not comments!

Answer (score 3):

Use `yum localinstall packagename.rpm`. It will resolve the dependencies, download and install them.

Comment: This is correct (but note that there's no need to do `localinstall` anymore — just regular `yum install` (or `dnf install`) will work on local files.